# Matching UPPERCASE, PascalCase and camelCase in single word

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have a string `testTESTCheckTESTAnother` and I want to split it in few words, like that `["test", "TEST", "Check", "TEST", "Another"]`.

#### Input:

Only [A-Za-z] characters allowed

```
testTESTCheckTESTAnother
```

#### Code:

My best try with regex was:

```
"testTESTCheckTESTAnother".match(/^[a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]*/g)
Output: ["test", "T", "E", "S", "T", "Check", "T", "E", "S", "T", "Another"]
```

I tried negative lookahead but it didn't work either:

```
"testTESTCheckTESTAnother".match(/?![A-Z][a-z]+)[A-Z]+/g)
Output: ["TESTC", "TESTA"]
```

#### Desired output:

```
["test", "TEST", "Check", "TEST", "Another"]
```

Other inputs-outputs:

```
input: "ITest"
output: ["I", "Test"]

input: "WHOLETESTWORD"
output: ["WHOLETESTWORD"]

input: "C"
output: ["C"]
```

Comment: How do you handle 1 letter Words ?

Comment: What if the string were "HANGMAN"? What should the results be?

Comment: how you divide input string on words?

Comment: if there's a specific rule on how the word is formed (starts with a lowercase then alternates uppercased and capitalized words) then it's possible to make a JS function to extract the words. Not so sure about the regex

Comment: How long is the list of words you want to match? (Reasonable vs Infinite)?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I've added it in the end of the question

Comment: @MikeBrockington of course reasonable, no more than ~80 characters.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me - I mean: is it reasonable to have a list of potential words to match against, along the lines of:  [wordOne, wordTwo].match(stringToBeTested)

Comment: @MaximeGirou one letter "x" would be a single element in array, like that ["x"]

Comment: @MikeBrockington there's no list of words. I have a function which uses this regex. Every function call would be working with one word, not a list or an array of strings.

Only problem here can be (as I can see it) is the length of input string, but as I said, it will be short enough.

Comment: @NebSehemvi what i mean is how you you know that if a word is not in realaity two words : `FOOBAR` or `foobar`. it seems to be pretty difficult with combinaison of PascalCase and Upper case : How can you spot teh difference between : `CHECKTest`-> ['CHECK', 'Test'] AND ['CHECKT', 'est'] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regular expression: `^[a-z]+|((?![A-Z][a-z])[A-Z])+|[A-Z][a-z]+`

See it in action at https://regex101.com/r/5r8MzJ/1

Explanation. We have three alternative patterns we will capture.

1. `^[a-z]+`

Accept a series of lowercase letters at the start of the string only.

2. `((?![A-Z][a-z])[A-Z])+`

Accept a series of uppercase letters except the last one if followed by a lowercase letter

3. `[A-Z][a-z]+`

Accept a series of one uppercase letter and at least one lowercase letters.

Comment: Same question as @User863, How do you do if the first world is UpperCase ? for example "FOOtestTESTCheckTESTAnother" will output [ "FO", "Otest", "TEST", "Check", "TEST", "Another" ]

Comment: @MaximeGirou Handling that case was not required in the question. It's not possible to differentiate between `FO Otest` and `FOO test` without using a dictionary. That's why I limited to accept all lowercase words only at the beginning of the string or a line.

Comment: Thanks!
Worked like a charm!

Comment: @MaximeGirou why do you need two different for same sort of case, `FOOtest` you want output as `FOO and test` and while for `TESTAnother` you want `TEST and Another`. how or on what basis you differentiate which way it should be splitted ?

Comment: As I understand the question, the input text is an identifier (for example from some source code) which is formatted in either PascalCase or camelCase or UPPERCASE and they want to get the individual words. So, there will not be a word part in all lowercase except at the beginning (when using camelCase)

Comment: i'm not the one who ask the question ! but  the way i understand the question seems this is an impossible question

Answer (score 2):

**Regex**

```
/[a-z]+|[A-Z]+(?=[A-Z]|$)|([A-Z][a-z]+)/g
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/wJvQBu/2)

`[a-z]+` - **Lowercase**

`[A-Z]+(?=[A-Z]|$)` - **Uppercase**

`([A-Z][a-z]+)` - **TitleCase**

```js
let string = "testTESTCheckTESTAnother"

console.log(string.match(/[a-z]+|[A-Z]+(?=[A-Z]|$)|([A-Z][a-z]+)/g))
```

Comment: How do you do if the first world is UpperCase ? for example "FOOtestTESTCheckTESTAnother" will output
[
  "FO",
  "Otest",
  "TEST",
  "Check",
  "TEST",
  "Another"
]

Comment: @CodeManiac @MaximeGirou For `SYNCheck` - `SYNC` and `heck`. For `SYNCCheck` - `SYNC` and `Check`. Which is not possible. You are asking to split words not cases

Comment: @NineBerry Its rectified now